# What is the best way to create a list from optional items in scala?

Tags: list, scala, optional-parameters

I have code that takes in a case class (ContentBlock) with a handful of Option fields. I want to create a list of objects (Description) built from those fields IF they are not "None" ... so I've made the following code, which works, but I strongly suspect is terrible. First, the match doesn't account for "None," it just drops any field with None on the floor, which the compiler properly tells me is bad.

What's the best pattern for doing something like this? Here's the code...

```
implicit def ContentBlockToDescriptionList(a: ContentBlock): List[Description] = {

  List[Description](
    a.instructions match {
      case Some(x) => new Description("Instructions", x)
    },
    a.terms_and_conditions match {
      case Some(x) => new Description("Terms and Conditions", x)
    },
    a.cancellation_addendum match {
      case Some(x) => new Description("Cancellation Addendum", x)
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the underlying type of each optional field is the same, you could write:

```
List(("Instructions", a.instructions),
     ("Terms and Conditions", a.terms_and_conditions),
     ("Cancellation Addendum", a.cancellation_addendum)
).collect {
  case (desc, Some(x)) => new Description(desc, x)
}
```

By the way, the original code won't "drop the None values on the floor"; it should be compiling with a non-exhaustive match warning, and will fail at runtime with a `MatchError`.

Comment: I get the warning. I do not get the error - the code runs. It should not?

Comment: If all of the values are `Some`, it won't fail. Try it with one of the values set to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it like this:

```
List(
  a.instructions map (new Description("Instructions", _)),
  a.terms_and_conditions map (new Description("Terms and Conditions", _)),
  a.cancellation_addendum map (new Description("Cancellation Addendum", _))
).flatten
```

Comment: I'm unclear on this - wouldn't this create three list elements, each a Description object? The second parameter to the Description constructor simply being the value from the a.whatever? And then flatten would have no effect, as all three elements would exist? That is, if a.instructions is None, doesn't it just add new Description("Instructions", None) ?

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler No, if `a.instructions` is `None`, then it would add `None`. Note that I'm calling the method `map` on the `Option`.

Comment: Got it. And thus the None(s) gets flattened-out. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler To be honest, I prefer Kristian's answer to my own.

Comment: Fair enough ;) ... but for my understanding, why? You prefer to let collect do the heavy lifting instead of flatten based on map setting the list value to None?

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler It's less repetition (`map (new Description(` appears three times in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `flatten`. like this:

```
implicit def ContentBlockToDescriptionList(a: ContentBlock): List[Description] =
  List[Option[Description]](
    a.instructions.map(new Description("Instructions", _)),
    a.terms_and_conditions.map(new Description("Terms and Conditions", _)),
    a.cancellation_addendum.map(new Description("Cancellation Addendum", _))
  ).flatten
```